# Downloading Multiple images from google

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, deep-learning

I am currently trying to make a deep learning model to differentiate between a teenager and a toddler, for which i require lots of images. I am not able to find how to download multiple images for this.
How can i download multiple images from google.

Comment: Checkout [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/04/how-to-create-a-deep-learning-dataset-using-google-images/) by Adrian -

Comment: Thanks. It was quite helpful.